# How do I mock or override Kernel.system?

Tags: ruby, mocking, testunit

How would be the correct way to mock or override the `Kernel.system` method so that when called with:

```
system("some command")
```

instead of executing the command, it executes some predefined code?

I tried adding the following to my Test class:

```
module Kernel
    def system
        puts "SYSTEM CALL!!"
    end
end
```

But it did not work as expected, instead, the system call was run when executing a test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about unit tests and use Rspec, you should be able to do it like this:

```
Kernel.should_receive(:system)
```

or a little more loose:

```
Kernel.stub(:system)
```

More info: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message

Comment: The link I gave you was from the official rspec docs: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/.
You can also check out http://betterspecs.org/ - it gives a number of best practices on how to use rspec properly.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about Unit tests, but unfortunately the code is not using rspec but simple Test Unit

Comment: In that case you should take a look at: https://github.com/freerange/mocha - `Kernel.expects(:system).returns(true)`

Comment: Does the `should_receive(:method_name)` stub the method so that it isn't executed? Or do you need to use `.stub(:method_name)` to prevent it from being executed?

Answer (score 14):

In some cases doing `expect(Kernel).to receive(:system)` is not enough.

Consider this example:

foo_component.rb

```
class FooComponent
  def run
    system('....')
  end
end
```

foo_component_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FooComponent do
  let(:foo_component) { described_class.new }

  describe '#run' do
    it 'does some awesome things' do
      expect(Kernel).to receive(:system).with('....')
      foo_component.run
    end
  end
end
```

It will not work. This is because `Kernel` is a module and `Object` (parent class) is mixes in the `Kernel` module, making all `Kernel` method available in "global" scope.

This is why proper tests should looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FooComponent do
  let(:foo_component) { described_class.new }

  describe '#run' do
    it 'does some awesome things' do
      expect(foo_component).to receive(:system).with('....')
      foo_component.run
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If it is within a class, kernel is mixed in. So you would just mock it as if it was part of the object.

E.g.

```
expect(subject).to receive(:system).and_return(foo)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this question was asked, RSpec 3 has come out with a new syntax, where you would write this:

```
expect(Kernel).to receive(:system)
```

If your code checks whether or not the system call was a success, you can specify the result like this:

```
expect(Kernel).to receive(:system).and_return(true)
```

The loose version:

```
allow(Kernel).to receive(:system).and_return(true)
```

Comment: FYI Using ruby 2.3.0 and rspec-core 3.4.2, I had to use `Kernel.system(...)` instead of just `system(...)` for the mock to pass.